# Custom query ignoring sticky entries

Tags: query, orderby, query-module

I'm using the query module, to return a list of entries sorted alphabetically, but there are a few sticky entries that I need to appear at the top of the list, and the stickies are being ignored.Here is my query:

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT entry_id AS rel_entry_id, title AS rel_title, (SELECT rel_child_id FROM exp_relationships WHERE rel_id = '{select-location}' LIMIT 1) AS rel_child_id FROM exp_channel_titles WHERE channel_id IN (5, 7) AND status='Open' ORDER BY title ASC "}
```

I tried adding sticky to my select, and 'sticky, title' to the ORDER BY parameter, but it didn't work. Is there a way to get it working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to add **sticky DESC**

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT entry_id AS rel_entry_id, title AS rel_title, (SELECT rel_child_id FROM exp_relationships WHERE rel_id = '{select-location}' LIMIT 1) AS rel_child_id FROM exp_channel_titles WHERE channel_id IN (5, 7) AND status='Open' ORDER BY sticky DESC, title ASC "}
```

Comment: That did it. I didn't even think about adding DESC. Thanks!